# Insert Controls in VB.NET Listview

Tags: vb.net

Hello I have a Listview in VB.NET and I want to insert inside it a name and a button as following: The name should be displayed in the left of the listview and the button in the right (just like if I have a row inside the listeview and the two controls placed in the left and right of that row) so, is it possible in VB.NET and if it's the case how?
I hope my question was clear.
Thanks.

Comment: A ListView is not a container window that can host other controls.  Like a Panel or a Form.  No, this is not possible.

Comment: Why not use DataGridView instead?

Comment: You can use Embedding Controls in a ListView "a custom ListView " see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9188/Embedding-Controls-in-a-ListView

Answer (score 4):

Not easily. However a DataGridView could handle this easily:

[image]

```
    DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(New DataGridViewColumn(1) _
                                    {New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With _
                                     {.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill, .HeaderText = "Text"},
                                     New DataGridViewButtonColumn() With _
                                     {.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill, .HeaderText = "Button"}})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add({"row 1 text", "row 1 button"})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add({"row 2 text", "row 2 button"})
```

These properties can be set from the designer, and you would probably bind the datagridview rather than add the rows manually.

EDIT to remove a row on button click, use the CellContentClick event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    'check it the button column being clicked, and check they are not clicking the column heading
    If e.ColumnIndex = 1 And e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

Note if you do use databinding, you should remove the row from the data object and not the datagridview

EDIT
Extracting all column on items to a list:

```
 Dim columnOneValues As New List(Of String)

 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        columnOneValues.Add(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
 Next
```

Comment: Hi, tanks so much for the answer, now How can I remove the first row on click on that first button "row 1 button"? and thanks.

Comment: @user1789193 edited with code. Will remove the row the user clicks the button on, so if they click the button on row 5, row 5 will be removed

Comment: @user1789193 Glad it helped. Please consider marking this as the accepted andswer

Comment: Hi, sorry I know that I'm asking to many question but this is the last one please: How can I extract all the values of the first column "Text" of the datagridview please?

Comment: @user1789193 see further edit

Comment: Hi, thanks so much I really apreciate your help, so this topic is now colsed. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** no.

**Longer answer:** yes, but this is nontrivial, and you can't do it with the stock `ListView`.

You'd have to extend the class, handle the drawing of the controls yourself, calculating their positions and dimensions according to the size of the `ListViewItem`. Furthermore, if a user reorders the `ListView` columns, there is no trivial way to get the new column order.

See [this codeproject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9188/Embedding-Controls-in-a-ListView) for an example of a custom `ListView`.